# Animate an imageView with changing constraints (progress bar) Swift

Tags: ios, swift, constraints, uiviewanimation

So, I am creating a sort of progress bar, mostly just an animation to go from 0 to 100 percent.  I have two images, one that is red on bottom, one on top that is black.  I am trying to take away from the top image to create the idea that it is loading from 0 to 100%, slowly revealing the image below.  I have all of that working, my problem is that I do not see the in between.  I see 0% and 100%, I can debug it and view the controller and see my view controller (self) updating and slowly taking away the top image so I know that it is working but I do not see it go through each animate.  I have edited one moved things around a ton but have not been able to see the changes.  Thanks for everyones help in advance!

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    if intCounter <= 100{
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.05, animations: catScanE.layoutIfNeeded)
        repeat {
            dblImageH = dblImageH - 3.80
            self.catScanE.frame = CGRect(x: 27  , y: 197, width: 320, height: dblImageH)
            intCounter = intCounter + 1
        } while  (intCounter <= 100)
    } else {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "lastSegue", sender: nil)
    }
}
```

I have gotten the animate to basically work, it scrolls down the screen but shows a type of animation.  I want it to slowly restrict the constraints but this is not the issue now.  Since the animation "works", I am not able to get it to segue after the animation, this is what I have.  Adding the if intCounter part makes it skip the animation and segue, without it the screen performs the animation and sits there...

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 5.0, animations: {
                self.dblImageH = self.dblImageH - 3.80
                self.catScanE.frame = CGRect(x: 27  , y: 197, width: 320, height: self.dblImageH)
                self.intCounter = self.intCounter + 1

                if self.intCounter > 100{
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "lastSegue", sender: nil)}
            })

}
```

I figured it out with some help from Ravron and more StackOverflow searching.  I set the content mode to top in the attributes and used this code to make it act like a progress bar (this is a black image with a red one underneath to  look like it is going from 0 to 100).  I ran into an issue with the image basically moving up or downwards, this was fixed by changing the y coordinate to match the change in size so it would basically stay in the same position.  I just need to figure out how to make a counter to go from 0 to 100 while it is animating.  Thanks!  Hopefully this can help someone else making a custom progress bar.

```
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 5.0, animations: {
                self.catScanE.frame = CGRect(x: 27  , y: 200, width: 320, height: 0)
            }, completion: {finished in self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "lastSegue", sender: nil)})
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `animate` block runs only once, and the final settings of the view's frame is all that counts. The view is actually being animated from 0% to 100% as you wish, but it happens in 50 milliseconds, or about three frames.

Just set the frame to the desired final position in the animate block and increase the duration to something reasonable, like `100 * 0.05s = 5s`.

To expand slightly: the `animate` method says, informally, "run the block below, which changes one or more traits of various views. Then, implicitly animate those traits from their current values to the values set when the block was run." So it's only called once, and in it you should set traits to their desired final values.

Consider reading through [the animations section of the View Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html) which gives a comprehensive overview of animation basics on the platform, and also covers UIView block-based animations, the type you're trying to use here.

Comment: So if I am understanding this correctly, I would need to remove the repeat/while and just have the image view constraints set to my final desired values which would be a 0 height.  The animate will make up the rest?

Comment: Yep. And set the duration to something reasonable. Read the docs for that method, too, while you're at it. :)

Comment: Any chance you could set me in the right direction regarding the docs?  I changed things around but was still ending up with 0 - 100...  Started looking for docs and ended up finding plenty not related to iOS 10, found one regarding 4.... FYI, I am a newbie regarding Swift and basically an entry level programmer so I know enough to do somethings but can easily get lost..  Sorry and thanks!  Your answer did make sense I just have no idea how to interpret that into the code especially when it comes to swift..?

Comment: I've added a link to documentation to the answer.

Comment: Recently have had a chance to pick this back up but have not been able to get it to work.  It again seems like it works but it does not update each time, I still see 0% and 100% and then it segues into the next view controller.  From the documentation it looks like the actions need to be included in the animation part?  I thought I was on the right track but it did not work at all.